# Problem on Lagrange multiplier (and KKT perhaps)

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the problem:
$$\min_{x, y} \{(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2\}$$
subject to
$$
\begin{cases}
2x + y \leq 4 \\
3x + 10y \leq 20 \\
x, y \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$
I have to solve this.

**Attempts**

So first of all I notice that without the constraints the min would lie at $(0, 0)$ since the function is a sum of two squares.

Anyway, I drew the constraints, which are two lines, and the lie in the first quadrant, since $x, y \geq 0$.

By the drawing I can conclude that only the first constraint is active, since the region created by the first constraint is contained in the region created by the second constraint, hence the feasible region is the first one (satisfying both constraints).

Now, since the two constraints are linear, I understood that max/min must lie on the boundary (if I'm wrong please correct me, and also I wouldn't mind some clarification about, either ways).

Now by Lagrange function I wrote:

$$L = (x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 - \lambda(x + 2y - 4) - \mu(3x + 10y - 20)$$

Whence the Lagrange equations read

$$
\begin{cases}
2(x-1) - \lambda - 3 \mu = 0 \\
2(y-2) - 2\lambda - 10\mu = 0 \\
x + 2y - 4 = 0 \\
3x + 10y - 20 = 0
x \geq 0\\
y \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$

Yet now I am stuck because I do not know how to exactly proceed.

I solved for the parameters:

$$\lambda = \dfrac{1}{2}(10x - 3y - 4) \qquad \qquad \mu = \frac{1}{2}y - x$$

Or else for $y = \lambda + 5\mu$ in terms of the multipliers.

Since only the first constraint is active, shall I forget about the second one?
Also, how to proceed in order to find a numerical solution?

Thank you

Comment: The min without the constraints lie at $(1,2)$. You should consider one  constraint at a time

Comment: @RobertZ Sorry, my bad! I meant that the min value for the two functions (separately) is zero, hence yes at $P = (1, 2)$.
Why do I need to consider one constraint at a time, when the second one is basically "too much"? If a point lies in the first region then it satisfies both, but I cannot have points that do not satisfy both. I guess...

Comment: Since the only stationary point is at $(1,2)$ which is outside the domain, then the minimum point is along the boundary

Comment: @RobertZ This is a thing I got not clearly: why exactly the minimum is along the boundary and not somewhere inside the domain?

Comment: A min/max inside should be a stationary point

Comment: You are looking for the closest point to $(1, 2)$ for the the region bounded by those inequalities. From here, the squared distance will be $(x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2$.

Comment: @TobyMak From the calculation I obtain the point $P = (0, 2)$

Comment: $(0, 2)$ can't be right. There is a shorter distance on the line $3x + 10y = 20$.

Comment: The Lagrange-multiplier method solves the **equality** case. So obtaining the global minimas of the function

$$L = (x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 - \lambda(x + 2y - 4) - \mu(3x + 10y - 20)$$

You get the optimal solution of $\min_{x, y} \{(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2\}$, with respect to

\begin{cases}
2x + y = 4 \\
3x + 10y = 20
\end{cases}

Which isn't the same problem as the one with $\leq$ signs.

However you can solve the original problem with [Quadratic optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming).

Comment: @DanielP So I had to write down the proper KKT equations. But I don't understand what I should add, besides what I already wrote, hence $x, y \geq 0$ and $\lambda, \mu \geq 0$...

Comment: @TobyMak There is one thing that is still not clear to me: I said in my question that only the first constraint is active, and the region created by it (the first line) is the feasible region. Yet the minimum point I found does not lie in this region (on its boundary) but it lies on the boundary of the second constraint. How is this possible / why? Doesn't this contradict the fact that only the first constraint is active? Shouldn't the point satisfy both constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the discussion in the comments, the minimum point is along the boundary which is made of four segments. As regards the constraint $3x + 10y=20$, you should consider the following system plus the extreme points:
$$\begin{cases}
2(x-1) - 3 \mu = 0 \\
2(y-2) - 10\mu = 0 \\
3x + 10y - 20 = 0\\
2x + y \leq 4, x \geq 0, y \geq 0
\end{cases}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, from here I got the solution $x = 100/109$ and $y = 188/109$. Considering the other two solutions obtained respectively from the first constraint only, and both ones, that one ($x = 100/109$ and $y = 188/109$) is the ones that returns $f(x, y)$ to have the minimum value!

Yet I do not understand a couple of things: $(1)$: I anyway obtain $\mu < 0$ in both cases. Shouldn't I obtain a positive value for the multipliers? 
$(2)$: why do I have inequality constraints but I made no use of KKT conditions?

Comment: (1) In KKT the lagrangian is with $+$ sign. (2) we have an equality constraint because we are along the boundary

Comment: Thank you!! Now it's clearer

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, there is one thing that is still not clear to me: I said in my question that only the first constraint is active, and the region created by it (the first line) is the feasible region. Yet the minimum point I found does not lie in this region (on its boundary) but it lies on the boundary of the second constraint. How is this possible / why? Doesn't this contradict the fact that only the first constraint is active? Shouldn't the point satisfy both constraints?

Comment: The boundary of the feasible region $\begin{cases}
2x + y \leq 4 \\
3x + 10y \leq 20 \\
x, y \geq 0
\end{cases}$ is given by four segments (linear constraints):
$\begin{cases}
2x + y= 4 \\
3x + 10y \leq 20 \\
x, y \geq 0
\end{cases}$, $\begin{cases}
2x + y \leq  4 \\
3x + 10y= 20 \\
x, y \geq 0
\end{cases}$, $\begin{cases}
2x + y \leq 4 \\
3x + 10y \leq 20 \\
x=0, y \geq 0
\end{cases}$, $\begin{cases}
2x + y \leq 4 \\
3x + 10y \leq 20 \\
x\geq 0,y=0
\end{cases}$